# using linux cat and grep command

Tags: linux, shell

I am having following syntax for one of my file.Could you please anyone explain me what is this command doing

```
    path = /document/values.txt
```

where we have different username specified e.g username1 = john,username2=marry

```
    cat ${path} | grep -e  username1 | cut -d'=' -f2`
```

my question here is cat command is reading from the file value of username1 but why why we need to use cut command?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cut_%28Unix%29

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cut -d'=' -f2`

This cut uses -d'=' that means you use '=' as 'field delimiter' and -f2 will take only de second field.

So in this case you want only the value after the "=" .

Answer (score 2):

Cat is printing the file.  The file has username1=something in one of the lines.  The cut command splits this and prints out the second argument.

Answer (score 2):

your command was not written well. the `cat` is useless.

you can do:

```
grep -e pattern "$path"|cut ...
```

you can of course do it with single process with `awk` if you like. anyway the line in your question smells not good.

awk example:

```
awk -F'=' '/pattern/{print $2}' inputFile
```

Comment: can you please give me an example,how can i write that using awk